# Derive Two Extended Control One inside Another in C# ToolBox

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have two controls inside my Class Library one named TextBox and one Panel, I am able to derive them differently in my ToolBox but what I want is instead of deriving two different controls I want my textbox inside the panel and derive just panel so that it contains both panel and textbox. I am facing an issue while doing it. Panel is easily available in Toolbox but the textbox object I created inside the Panel is not visible. Can anyone tell me is this thing achievable?

```
public class TextBoxPanel :Panel
{
    TextBoxPanel()
    {
        IpTextBox ip = new IpTextBox();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public class IPField : TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Atleast you need to add your textbox to your panel. e.g. `Controls.Add(ip);`

Comment: Where should i write this line ? @yolosora

Comment: for example in your panel constuctor after textbox creating @himanshu

Comment: I checked in constructor it's not working but somehow it worked when i instantiate in OnPaint() method. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend from multiple base classes. Your intuition to derive from your `Panel` is correct since you want a `TextBox` inside a `Panel`.

The big question is WHY do you "need" to derive from `TextBox`? If you just need a `TextBox` inside your new control then simply adding an instance of it to your Panel is enough.

If the `TextBox` provides additional functionality through an API which you want to expose from the new `TextBoxPanel` then I suggest something along these lines:

```
public interface ICoolStuff
{
   public String HelloWorld();
}

public class TextBox : Control, ICoolStuff
{
    // *snip*
}

public class TextBoxPanel : Panel, ICoolStuff
{
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return this.textbox.HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

IF the functionality your textbox provides is not dependent on the textbox itself then it would be even better to separate it into a completely different class

Comment: It's actually the Panel on which i had defined shadowing affect so i want that shadowing around my textbox that's the reason i chose to put textbox inside a panel.